# android phone displays numbers info even for uknown ones to my adressbook

Tags: calls

A question of a general nature, the call to the numbers of which is not in the phone book. android shows information such as a call name. where does this information come from, if the source is open and google take it from web, can this information be changed?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what device you have, what Android version it runs, and what apps you've installed. Raw guess: Open your phone app, tap the 3 vertical dots in the upper-right corner, and check the settings. Most likely there's some CallerID service enabled. Or you've installed a specific CallerID app – but then you wouldn't ask. Though, such an app might have been pre-installed on your device, so that's something else you can check.

Comment: using native android 8.1 telephone app. on nokia

Comment: Thanks Yurij. Which Nokia? And have you checked the places I've mentioned?

Comment: I have to clarify that this outbound/incoming call info is related to external things such a mobile network and area telephone network. as this caller info is propagated for any other android phones. (samsung, meizu, no matter case). I suppose that google collect that info in some place. I don't know how to correct is without contact creating. may be it worth to ask google suppport

Comment: Yurij, we cannot much help you if you don't provide the details we need. So again: Have you checked the places indicated above? What have you found?

Comment: Thanks, once i v checked settings, i found it. that is https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/3459196?visit_id=1-636694071743884895-233081447&p=dialer_google_caller_id&rd=2&hl=en

Comment: _Caller ID by Google shows the names of companies and services with a Google My Business listing. It also looks for matches in any directory that shows caller information for work or school accounts._ [ref](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/3459196?visit_id=1-636694071743884895-233081447&p=dialer_google_caller_id&rd=2&hl=en)
If you want you can answer my question, as you push me to that discovery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81393/discussion-between-yurij-and-izzy).

Comment: Please don't forget to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) as promised :)